# Grails Remote Function and Ajax

Tags: grails

I am trying to list addresses and onChange event I send the address ID and return a list of users.

```
<g:select name="AddressID" from="${address}" optionKey="id" optionValue="address"
              onchange="${ remoteFunction(
                           action:'testMe', 
                           params:'\'id=\' + this.value' ,
                           update:'show' )}">
      </g:select>
```

I call this div "show".

```
<div id="show">
  <g:each in="${users}" status="i" var="C">
        <h3>${C}</h3>
  </g:each>

</div>
```

However, when I click the item on the list box I get the following error:
`description The requested resource (/MyTest/WEB-INF/grails-app/views/test/testMe.jsp) is not available.`

My understanding of an update attribute inside a remoteFunction is that it is the name of the div which gets refreshed after the remoteFunction call is compeleted.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would reorganize your code a little to get the Ajax working:

1. Move your `div` contents into a partial template, called, say, `_remoteResponse.gsp`:

   `<g:each in="${users}" status="i" var="C">` 
        `<h3>${C}</h3>`
   `</g:each>`
2. Modify your controller's `testMe` action to render the response to a template, something like:

`render (template:'remoteResponse', model:[users:['mike,tim']])`

- Make sure you have an ajax library setup in `main.gsp`, like:

`<g:javascript library="prototype" />`